# Преобразование в EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, mobile-development

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть 2 EditText И 1 textView. TextView со статичным значением '20'. В первый EditText вводится числo не больше 20, а во второй EditText присваивается разность между TexView и EditText. Помогите реализовать и разобраться с преобразование из String в Integer.

Comment: В таких случаях нужно приводить ваш код и стэктрейсы ошибок в виде текста, чтоб можно было скопировать и повторить, а не разглядывать на скриншоте, что же там в коде происходит

Answer (score 0):

```
int difference = Integer.parseInt(textView().getText()) -
         Integer.parseInt(editText().getText().toString);

myText.setText (String.valueOf(difference));
```

Comment: Выдает вот такую ошибку (скриншот в описании вопроса) . Плюс я еще добавит .toString() перед textView().getText()) в твоем ответе.

Comment: Дополню, что желательно такое обрабатывать в `try/catch`, так как метод `parseInt` может выбросить исключение `NumberFormatException`

Comment: надо число назад в `String` привести. Обновил ответ

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо)